# Menu with list of option using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, menu

i'm trying to get the Menu with different style in jquery mobile with list of choices in the page footer.Like as shown below.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

**Updated:**

```
    $('body').bind('hideOpenMenus', function(){
    $("ul:jqmData(role='menu')").find('li > ul').hide();
}); 
var menuHandler = function(e) {
    $('body').trigger('hideOpenMenus');
    $(this).find('li > ul').show();
    e.stopPropagation();
};
$("ul:jqmData(role='menu') li > ul li").click(function(e) {
   $('body').trigger('hideOpenMenus');
e.stopPropagation();
});
$('body').delegate("ul:jqmData(role='menu')",'click',menuHandler);
$('body').click(function(e){
   $('body').trigger('hideOpenMenus');
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kfnsy/ code is here

Comment: Where is the footer? What have you tried. Don't just use Fiddle, post your code here so people can learn from it.

Comment: The fiddle which i posted is with header not with footer. When i'm getting this menu in footer it shows the items under the menu.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest solution there is, no javascript or CSS, basically pure jQuery Mobile solution.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PMrDn/58/

#### HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>
            
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a">
                        <li data-icon="arrow-r"><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                        <li data-icon="grid"><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                        <li data-icon="info"><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Index page</h1>                
                <a href="#popupMenu" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop">Next</a>                
            </div>            
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your fiddle is working but when i'm  opened in the browser..its looks like normal html page only

Comment: That is because you must uncomment jquery initialization, it is not needed for jsFiddle example but you still need it to run this example successfully.

Comment: yes its working but can we make this menu looks like in the above image

Comment: Thank you for making fiddle but this is normal one compared to image

Comment: What are you talking about, normal what?

Comment: sorry i mean this is also looks like same as in before fiddle.. only the options changes and css

Comment: What more do you want?

Comment: i need the menu with same style in the above image. can we do this same as in the image ?

Comment: Yes, I can do that but I am not going to, this is not u pure man's freelancer site. If you want to add a arrow to that popup feel free to do that by yourself.

Comment: yes yes..but my question is that only..before only i did like what you  did now in fiddle

Comment: @Gajotres..one doubt why if i remove the <h1> in footer...Menu is not working properly..?? http://jsfiddle.net/PMWvP/

Comment: Just change <h1> to this: <h1>&nbsp;</h1>  , footer will still be there but there will be no text.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k5FUF/4/ can you please check this one before placing the Menu button. When i clicked on the list items it will open in a new page(dynamic page) but after placing the menu button.When i clicked on the list item nothing is happening..

Comment: @Gajotres..Can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907986/listdividers-in-the-listview-along-with-the-description-dynamically-using-jquery